# Docker / NodeJS: "exec: \"-d\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am having a problem running Docker container after upgrading from NodeJS 8.2 to 9.1. This is the message I am getting.

I used the Dockerfile I found in Docker Hub but got an error of not being able to find package.json. So I commented it out and use the one I found on NodeJS website.

Below is the Docker File:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:9.1.0
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ONBUILD ARG NODE_ENV
ONBUILD ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
ONBUILD COPY package*.json ./
ONBUILD RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force 
ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app 

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I would appreciate help from more experienced users.

Answer (score 2):

Your `docker run` command syntax is wrong. Everything after the image name is used to override the command run in your container. So `docker run myimage -d` will try to run `-d` inside the container, while `docker run -d myimage` will run your container with the `-d` option to docker run (detached mode).

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile you referenced is meant to be used as parent image for an easy dockerization of your application.

So to dockerize your nodejs application, you'd need to create a dockerfile using the docker image created by said dockerfile.

The `ONBUILD` instruction gets executed whenever a new image is built with this particular image as parent image (`FROM` instruction). [More info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild)

I've never used an image like this, but from the looks of it, it should be enough to reference the image with the `FROM` instruction and then provide the `NODE_ENV` via build args.

The dockerfile to add into your project:

```
FROM this_image:9.1
```

How to build your application image:

```
docker build -t IMAGE_NAME:TAG --build-arg NODE_ENV=production .
```